# Graph QL query with variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

GraphQL, Gatsby plugin sharp and react: I'm trying to include a javascript calculation of device.width in my query, but I can't seem to get it working. The goal is to query based on the client's device screen width, so that the site can serve responsive images. I'm trying to get it working like this, with deviceWidth returning an Int, and passing it through to the query as an argument to responsiveSizes:

```
const deviceWidth = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query BlogPostBySlug($slug: String! ) {
  markdownRemark(fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
    html
    timeToRead
    excerpt
    frontmatter {
      title
      cover
      date
      category
      tags
      thumbnail {
        childImageSharp {
          responsiveSizes(maxWidth: deviceWidth, quality: 50, cropFocus: CENTER, toFormat: JPG) {
          src
          srcSet
          sizes
          base64
          }
        }
      }
    }
    fields {
      slug
    }
  }
}
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this approach will work with Gatsby.

Gatsby builds static HTML which gets saved to disk and served to the user. Then React gets booted and takes over the DOM. In your approach, the data to be included in the `pageQuery` is calculated from the browser. That means that the `pageQuery` will be unique for every user.

I think something like the [gatsby-image](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-image) plugin will solve this problem for you.

I guess it gets all the relevant data from GraphQL so your query is consistent, then decides on the client which version to load.